# jquery charts - как нарисовать диаграмму пирог?

Tags: jquery

Из php я получаю данные процентов. В сумме всегда получается 100. Как мне можно нарисовать диаграмму пирог на основе полученных данных?

Пример данных - 61.44%, 38.26%, 0.29%, 0.01%

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может быть вам это поможет - https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/piechart-ggplot2.html

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart?hl=ru  мллион их здесь - любой использйуте

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery?hl=ru вот голерея

Comment: вот еще в догонку highcharts, там дофига разных типов графиков и их кастомизации. идея такая же как у гугловых: чтобы нарисовать график, пишете код на javascript (данные можете через ajax получить). вот ссылка на демки от них: https://www.highcharts.com/demo (выберите понравившуюся и копируете код себе на страницу)